# Length of OF_packet_data exceeding total length of OF_IN_packet

Tags: mininet, openflow, openvswitch

I am parsing openflow packets using java by opening 6633 port and listening to OF packets.

My code is breaking for some openflow PACKET_IN packets. See the following image.

---

I am simulating topology using mininet.

```
mn --mac --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13 --controller remote,ip=172.23.107.166,port=6633 --ipbase=2.2.2.0/24 --topo linear,10
```

Mininet vesion: 2.2.1rc1

Openvswitch version: 2.0.2

---

Following is the screenshot of wireshark capture.

[image]

---

You can observe that Total Length (342) is exceeding Length (170).

Because of this my java code is parsing extra packet bytes (because of inappropriate data length:342) i.e. bytes from  next packet, thereby the following packets parsed are being corrupted.

It should stop parsing after reading 170 bytes. And then parsing for next of packet should start.

> Can you explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The TCP segment length of 170 bytes is just that - the number of bytes in the *current* segment.  Since the openflow total length is 342 bytes, its data spans multiple TCP segments, so your java code needs to be able to deal with this.

Comment: Hi Christopher, are you suggesting to segment out the buffer into 170 byte segments? Currently, the buffer moves onto parse the next segment in the buffer when the entire Openflow packet is parsed, i.e. including the OFType - OFPacketIn.. So as soon as the data in the packet-in is read to it's limit, the buffer is moved to the next segment's position.. The problem that is being seen is 1st packet is parsed correctly, and then entire buffer is being read, i.e, all subsequent segments.. Should there be a hard 170 byte segment check, and as soon as it is met, position is pointed to next segment?

Comment: No, for whatever reason, 170 bytes/342 bytes were sent in this segment, which means another segment(s) will contain the remaining 172 bytes.  TCP is a streaming protocol and segments do not necessarily coincide with packets.

So, your Java app should first read 14 bytes to obtain the total length and then read that many more bytes (less 14 if they're already included in the total length).  If there aren't that many bytes in the current segment, then it should save the bytes it read so far and continue reading until it has read all 342 bytes.  At that point, it will have the entire payload.

Comment: After re-reading the [Openflow spec][1], I think my earlier assumption was wrong.  The total length appears to be the number of bytes in the message, of which only "length" bytes have been sent to the controller.  This seems to make more sense in that the Openflow and TCP length match and Wireshark indicates a malformed bootp packet, which is likely what would happen if the packet was truncated.  So in the end, this looks normal and should be expected.

[1]: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos597E/papers/openflow-spec-v1.3.2.pdf

Comment: Interesting.. Btw, we are using `OF 1.3.0` here.. Also, this happens only with `OVS 2.0.2`.. Once OVS is upgraded to `2.5.0`, we no longer see these `malformed dhcp` packets.. The problem area is only in the Packet `Payload`.. So then the conclusion is that the java code needs to handle these `bootp/dhcp` packets??

Comment: My reading of 7.4.1 indicates that only `max_len` bytes or `miss_send_len` bytes (default=128) could be sent depending on action; therefore any application attempting to process the payload ought to be able to handle truncated messages.  You should be able to tell if it's truncated if total length > length.  BTW, what does Wireshark show with OVS 2.5.0?  Does it show total length = length?  Maybe the `max_len` value changed between versions and it's possible to increase the value for OVS 2.0.2 to match OVS 2.5.0?

Comment: Hi Christopher, not sure if WS shows total length = length.. Will have to check.. Will update with the results..